# adding a command server capability to my vscode extension

Tags: vscode-extensions

a vscode Webview enables me to execute workspace commands via an href of the form "command:my.cmd"....  i'm looking to implement a "remote" form of this capability, whereby some client app (eg, a webpage) can request my running instance of vscode to execute a command....

to simplify the problem, let's assume the webpage wishing to command vscode is running on the **same** machine -- and hence could use a local socket....

does my extension simply open up a socket (or perhaps a websocket) on 127.0.0.1 and then listen for incoming commands????

Comment: Yes. Your vscode extension is ultimately running a nodejs instance.

Answer (score 0):

here's what i've learned, which validates this approach....

- you can definitely create a node.js `WebSocketServer` within a vscode extension
- that server can listen, for example, on `localhost:5000`
- a client web-page, using the JS `WebSocket` API, can connect to `localhost:5000`
- the client can send a message, and then either close the connection or keep it warm

this is much simpler than i had originally imagined, and hope this approach might help others....  my particular use-case is to create web-pages for training purposes, which can automatically perform vscode operations (open a file, highlight a line, fire off a build, etc) under a pace set by the viewer of these pages....

i've looked at vscode tours, but the UI doesn't have the richness of (say) mkdocs material which i use to source my webpages....